# JQuery Popover On Calculations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I ran into a problem with my JQuery. I have been doing a calculator for certain items and quantity and originally made a popup `.alert` above the name and moved the whole row of items below it. To fix this problem I want to have a Twitter Bootstrap v3.0.3 popover triggered by the live calculation of the number of items times the price of one item.

`What I want to do:`

```
 //Stone
 $("#Stone").on('keyup',function(){
   // alert('pressed')
   var CostStone= $("#StonePrice").val() * $(this).val()
   var CostStone2 = CostStone.toFixed(2);
   $(".CostStone").html(" data-toggle='popover' ");
 });
 //End Stone
```

I know this won't work, but somehow I need someone to come up with a JQuery alternative for
`data-toggle` so that I can trigger the popover while typing in an input box.

If you want to see my original idea just to get an idea of what I'm talking aboutcheck out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hawkeyestrike/6dVPd/6/).

Comment: seems more complicated than necessary...and doesn't make sense to replace full element html each keyup...why can't you just position the calculated values within each row and update the text on keyup, hide on blur

Comment: What's `.html(" data-toggle='popover' ")` supposed to do? Did you mean to set an attribute `data-toggle` instead? If so, use `$(".CostStone").attr("data-toggle", "popover");` instead

Answer (score 0):

modify your javascript with this

```
//Stone
 $("#Stone").on('keyup',function(){
       var stoneprice = $("#StonePrice").val();
       var currentprice = $(this).val();
       var CostStone=  Number(stoneprice) * Number(currentprice); 
       var CostStone2 = CostStone.toFixed(2);
     $(".CostStone").html(" data-toggle='popover' ");
   });
//End Stone
```